# MvvmCross 6 navigation ignoring presentation attributes in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, navigation, mvvmcross

I have the application with tab controller with 4 tabs, so 4 VMs each with corresponding view.
Each view has presentation attribute - `MvxTabPresentation`

But the thing is I want to have a possibility of navigating to one of these VMs as to child view (i.e. opening it from another tab as a child).

As I understand I should use [Presentation Hints](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/view-presenters#requesting-presentation-changes), but I don't understand how as it seems not to be well documented feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution so answering here by myself:

You must change the presentation attribute at runtime in case you want to show the View Controller differently.

Here is the mentioning about it in MvvmCross documentation: [solution](https://www.mvvmcross.com/mvvmcross-6.0.0-release/#viewpresenters).